# Remove Control Control from Word document after generating a document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, office-automation

I have a C# document generation component which inserts content into control controls in a word document and everything is working well.

The only problem is that in the generated document, the content controls are still there and you cannot select individual lines or text.

I need to remove these content controls and I thought that the content control property "Remove content control when contents are editing" is exactly what I was looking for, as my component would be changing the control content. However, it does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have a look at the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448297/replacing-content-controls-in-openxml

Comment: Thanks but the code in the sample doesn't work, and the I have set the temporary property to true through the Content Control Properties GUI. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In one of the samples in http://worddocgenerator.codeplex.com content controls are removed from the document while keeping the content. The specific method is RemoveContentControlsAndKeepContents(Document document)

Comment: Here are some newer links for this: [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/atverma/2018/09/18/utility-to-generate-word-documents-from-templates-using-visual-studio-2017-and-documentformat-openxml-2-8/), [GitHub](https://github.com/atverma/WordDocGenerator)